# Запускаю бота в телеграм хочу проверить

Tags: node.js

Открываю `./index.js`

А там вот это

> error: [polling_error] {"code":"EFATAL","message":"EFATAL: Error:
>   connect ETIMEDOUT 119.154.167.221:443"}

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: из-за чего это?

Comment: Из-за того, что указанный адрес не принимает соединения по указанному порту.

Comment: Вы где-то пропустили информацию о том, что Telegram заблокирован в России уже больше полугода? Смиритесь.

Comment: если использовать или ssh в связке с проксифаер?

Comment: Помидоры все же принесли в студию :) А по сути, использовать надо прокси, но практического интереса, мне кажется это не представляет, в связи с отсутствием вменяемой российской аудитории.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже недавно столкнулся с блокировкой телеги. Из возможных решений - арендовать хостинг за  границей и оттуда уже коннектиться к серверам телеги. Разработка немного усложняется в силу прямой правки на сервере.
Либо ставить у себя на локалке vpn и спокойно работать.